# How to externalize an insert file SQL query

Tags: java, sql

In my application, I want to externalize SQL query (in .properties files for example). But sometimes I had to insert the entire content of a text file into a CLOB column.

This is the code I use now:

```
 String requete = "the content of the file in xml";
 PreparedStatement prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"TABLE\".\"_XML\" (ID, BLOC_XML) VALUES ('1',?)");
 prepareStatement.setCharacterStream(1, new StringReader(requete), requete.length());
```

I really need to decouple the SQL logic from the application business logic. Any suggestions to tackle this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to externalize the SQL queries. Imagine that someone would change the .properties file to something like

```
drop table really_important_stuff;
```

Furthermore, as a developer I would prefer to have the SQL queries as close to the source code as possible. So that I do not need to look them up in some other resource.

It's simple to gain control of the complexity using [DAO pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) for example.